# Is it safe to initialize a c++11 function-static variable from a linux signal handler?

Tags: linux, c++11, signals

2 questions (below) about the C++11 static initialization at [1] in this reference code (this is a complete tested c++11 example program).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Foo {
    /* complex member variables. */
};

void DoSomething(Foo *foo) {
    // Complex, but signal safe, use of foo. 
}

Foo InitFoo() {
    Foo foo;
    /* complex, but signal safe, initialization of foo */
    return foo;
}

Foo* GetFoo() {
    static Foo foo = InitFoo();   // [1]
    return &foo;
}

void Handler(int sig) {
    DoSomething(GetFoo());
}

int main() {
    // [2]

    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = Handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, nullptr);

    for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
        DoSomething(GetFoo());
    }
}
```

Question1:  Is this guaranteed safe (no deadlocks etc)?  C++11 static initialization involves locks.  What if the signal is delivered before/after/during the first call to GetFoo() in main?

Question2:  Is this guaranteed safe if a call to GetFoo() is inserted at [2] before the signal handler is installed?  (Edit:) I.e. does inserting GetFoo() at [2] ensure that, later, when a signal arrives while the loop is operating, that there will be no deadlock?

I'm assuming C++11 (g++ or clang) on recent GNU/Linux, although answers for various Unices would also be interesting.  (Spoiler: I think the answer is 1:NO and 2:YES but I don't know how to prove it.)

Edit: To be clear, I can imagine static initialization could be implemeted like this:

```
Mutex mx;           // global variable
bool done = false;  // global variable
...
lock(mx);
if (!done) {
  foo = InitFoo();
  done = true;
}
unlock(mx);
```

and then it would not be deadlock safe because the signal handler might lock mx while the main thread has it locked.

But there are other implementations, for example:

```
Mutex mx;                        // global variable
std::atomic<bool> done = false;  // global variable
...
if  (!done.load()) {
  lock(mx);
  if (!done.load()) {
    foo = InitFoo();
    done.store(true); 
  }
  unlock(mx);
}
```

which would not have potential for deadlock provided the codepath was run completely at least once before a signal handler runs it.

My question is whether the c++11 (or any later) standard requires the implementation to be async-signal-safe (deadlock free, aka lock free) *after* the initial pass through the code has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `static Foo foo = InitFoo();` gets initialized must be stated first before getting into signals.

It requires [*dynamic initialization*](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4), where it'll be initialized the first time `GetFoo()` gets called since the "complex initialization" you mention in `InitFoo()` can't be done at compile-time:

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage
> duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time
> control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered
> initialized upon the completion of its initialization. If the
> initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is
> not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters
> the declaration. **If control enters the declaration concurrently while
> the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait
> for completion of the initialization. <sup>85</sup> If control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being initialized, the
> behavior is undefined.**
>
> **<sup>85</sup> The implementation must not introduce any deadlock around execution of the initializer. Deadlocks might still be caused by the program logic; the implementation need only avoid deadlocks due to its own synchronization operations.**

With that established, we can go to the questions.

> Question1: Is this guaranteed safe (no deadlocks etc)? C++11 static initialization involves locks. What if the signal is delivered before/after/during the first call to GetFoo() in main?

No, this isn't guaranteed. Consider when `GetFoo()` is called the first time from inside the `for` loop:

```
GetFoo() -> a lock is taken to initialize 'foo'-> a signal arrives [control goes to signal handling function] -> blocked here for signal handling to complete
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
--> Handler() -> DoSomething(GetFoo()) -> GetFoo() -> waits here because the lock is unavailable.
```

(The signal handler has to wait here since the initialization of 'foo' isn't complete yet -- refer the quote above).

So the deadlock occurs in this scenario (even without any threads) as the thread is blocked on itself.

> Question2: Is this guaranteed safe if a call to GetFoo() is inserted at [2] before the signal handler is installed?

In this case, there's no signal handler established at all for SIGINT. So if `SIGINT` arrives, the program simply exits. The *default* disposition for SIGINT is to terminate the process. It doesn't matter whether the initialization of `GetFoo()` is progress or not. So this is fine.

The fundamental problem with case (1) is that the signal handler `Handler` isn't [async-signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) because it calls `GetFoo()` which isn't async-signal-safe.

---

Re. updated question with possible implementations of static initialization:

The C++11 standard only guarantees that the initialization of `foo` is done in a thread-safe manner (see the bold quote above). But handling signals is not "concurrent execution". It's more like "recursively re-entering" as it can happen even in a single-threaded program - and thus it'd be undefined. This is true even if static initialization is implemented like in your second method that'd avoid deadlocks.

Put it the other way: if static initialization is implemented like your first method, does it violate the standard? The answer is no. So you can't rely on static initialization being implemented in an async-signal-safe way.

Given you ensure "...provided the codepath was run completely at least once before a signal handler runs it." then you could introduce another check that'd ensure `GetFoo()` is async-signal-safe regardless of how static initialization is implemented:

```
std::atomic<bool> foo_done = false;
static_assert( std::atomic<bool>::is_lock_free );

Foo* GetFoo() {
    if (!foo_done) {
        static Foo foo = InitFoo();   // [1]
        foo_done = true;
    }
    return &foo;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it does not completely answer the question#2  I intended to ask.  The question is not whether the call to GetFoo() inserted at [2] is ok.  The question is: by inserting the GetFoo() at [2], which ensures that the static foo has been initialized before the signal handler is established, do I guarantee that deadlock cannot occur later when a signal arrives while the main thread is executing GetFoo()?

If static initialization is implemeted like

Comment: I've clarified the question.  If you can update your answer to answer that then I will certainly accept this answer!

Comment: @Acorn I think I misunderstood question #2. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you!!  Terrific and very helpful answer!

Comment: I believe in the example code, the return statement has to be moved outside the conditional.  I submitted an edit suggestion to make that change.  Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: @Acorn Indeed. Accepted the correction. Thanks!